# Classify keyword in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, classifyjs

```
Classify ("cs.views/SelectorView", "BaseView",{
    templateId: '';
    function abc(){
    }
});
```

TemplateId is the filname of the template we have created for the webpage. But can someone tell me what Classify does in JavaScript. I have never heard of it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Classify isn't part of native javascript, it's a third-parties library.
See definition of what Classify fetched from [official website](http://classifyjs.com/) below:

Classify.js is a library that allows for cross browser and cross platform Object Oriented Javascript class definitions using classical inheritance patterns and namespaces behind the prototype syntax of javascript in an easy to use interface function.